# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl; in class Lokhttp3/HttpUrl; or its super classes

Tags: android, gradle, retrofit, okhttp

My project was working fine before integrating  [Small case Library](https://developers.gateway.smallcase.com/docs/android-integration). After integration I'm getting this error at the time of installing application.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method get(Ljava/lang/String;)Lokhttp3/HttpUrl; in class Lokhttp3/HttpUrl; or its super classes (declaration of 'okhttp3.HttpUrl' appears in /data/app/base.apk!classes3.dex)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$Builder.baseUrl(Retrofit.java:506)
```

here I'm attaching App level gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/*'
    }
    defaultConfig {
       
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 29
       
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    configurations{
        all*.exclude module: 'okhttp'
        all*.exclude module: 'okio'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }




    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

}




dependencies {
    implementation project(path: ':library')
    implementation project(path: ':library')
    implementation project(path: ':library')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
 
    implementation 'com.smallcase.gateway:sdk:2.9.3'

    implementation ('com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0') {
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.4.1'
   

}
```

As mentioned in other answers I have already tried setting CompileOptions with Java 1.8. but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are forcing an older version of okhttp which is breaking things.  You should either be using 3.12.13 or 4.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

use both the newest version (Retrofit & OkHttp)

https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3058

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30179101)